# TML Theme My Login Plugin

Tags: plugins, php

I'm trying to redirect the user to a "Thank you for signing up" page but I can not get it.

This is the code (It's wrong)

```
function tml_action_url( $url, $action, $instance ) {
    if ( 'login' == $action )
        $url = 'url/thanks';
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'tml_action_url', 'tml_action_url', 10, 3 );
?>
```

But it does not work as I want.

Once the user registers, he takes me to the url:

url/?checkemail=registered

I do not know how to reference it.

Any ideas?

Greetings, thank you.

Comment: You should ask the developer of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in the add_action needs to be the name of the filter you are trying to 'hook' into. There is no hook called 'tml_action_url'.

Figure out the hook you want to use, and use that hook name in the add_action.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `redirect_to="/url/thanks/"` to your shortcode.

Comment: This looks more like a comment that should have been added to the answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/185127)

Comment: @rudtek this is an answer, as there is more than one way to achieve the same result with the plugin being referred to.